Why is Altium giving me a strange clearance message?
I'm using Altium 24.1.2 to design a multi-layer PCB, and I'm using the "Full-Stack" via rules to reduce the sizes of vias in some layers. I have done this successfully on other PCBs.

 
However, on this particular PCB, I'm getting a lot of strange errors:
Clearance Constraint: (0.035mm < 0.16mm) Between Polygon Region (13 hole(s)) Mid Layer 4 And Via (207mm,97.725mm) from Top Layer to Bottom Layer
Note the measurement of 0.035mm. The clearance between the hole and the polygon is 0.16mm as it should be. (Although the measurement is 0.165 because this polygonal hole is only an approximation of a circle)

0.35mm is actually the distance between the polygon clearance, and the edge of the via on another layer!

Why on earth am I getting this error? It doesn't seem to make sense.

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

@ChrisKnudsen - Thanks. I am already a member there. But I value the experience (and answering speed) of the people here. I believe it's quite common for people to ask Altium related questions here. I have even answered one myself.

Perhaps a measurement on layer 4 polygon to pad on layer 4. Check the pad size for each layer of the stack up.

@RussellH - I'm not sure what you mean. The pad size on layer 4 is 0.2mm, as you can see in the image.

This is a bug in Altium. If you close Altium, and open it again, the errors go away.

For the sake of future reference - can you add which Altium version you are using to the question and answer? I had a similar issue in v24.5.2 wherein adding fencing vias to a net was inexplicably incomplete but worked after a restart.
